# TIBCO Business Works

Tags: automated-testing

We are in the process of implementing [TIBCO Business Works](http://www.tibco.de/products/automation/application-integration/activematrix-businessworks) as part of our new service layer.

We aim to test this in isolation, so black box testing and then attached our legacy back end database.

We will likely use a test harness so we can create a fully automated suite. The harness will either be bought or built internally.

I am looking for peoples experiences in testing:

- This product or similar service bus products?
- What type of strategy did you take?
- Did you build your own harness or go out to market?

Comment: What are the services that you intended to test? Is it like soap / rest / http / jdbc etc?